# Sorting Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the dataset shown below. I am trying to sort it so that the columns are in this order: Week End, Australia, Germany, France, etc...

I have tried using `loc` and assigning each of the data sets as variables but when I create a new DataFrame it causes an error. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the data before any changes:

| Region | Week End | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | 2014-01-11 | 1.480510 |
| Germany | 2014-01-11 | 1.481258 |
| France | 2014-01-11 | 0.986507 |
| United Kingdom | 2014-01-11 | 1.973014 |
| Italy | 2014-01-11 | 0.740629 |

This is my desired output:

| Week End | Australia | Germany | France | United Kingdom | Italy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-11 | 1.480510 | 1.481258 | 0.986507 | 1.973014 | 0.740629 |

What I've tried:

```
cols = (['Region','Week End','Value'])
df = GS.loc[GS['Brand'].isin(rows)]
df = df[cols]
AUS = df.loc[df['Region'] == 'Australia']
JPN = df.loc[df['Region'] == 'Japan']
US = df.loc[df['Region'] == 'United States of America']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could actually just do:

```
df.pivot(index="Week End", columns="Region", values="Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

User 965311532's answer is much more concise, but an alternative approach using dictionaries would be:

```
new_df = {'Week End': df['Week End'][0]}
new_df.update({region: value for region, value in zip(df['Region'], df['Value'])})
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df, index = [0])
```

As user 965311532 pointed out, the above code will not work if there are more dates. In this case, we could use pandas `groupby`:

```
dates = []
for date, group in df.groupby('Week End'):
    date_df = {'Week End': date}
    date_df.update({region: value for region, value in zip(df['Region'], df['Value'])})
    date_df = pd.DataFrame(date_df, index = [0])
    dates.append(date_df)
new_df = pd.concat(dates)
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if you have more than one `Week End` value, as it specifically targets the first row of the DataFrame

Comment: That is true. If there were more `Week End` values, I think I would use pandas `groupby` first.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment.  Dictionaries will actually help me with another data set I plan to work on. Thanks again